# Drawing circles with SDL2?

Tags: c++, geometry, sdl-2

is there a sdl "draw circle" function? or should i make it from cero?
or, instead of that... is there an already made function in c++ for that?

something like:

```
int main (){
  // create the window
  SDL_Window * window1 =
        SDL_CreateWindow("Window",700,50,500,450, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  // create the renderer
  SDL_Renderer * renderer =  SDL_CreateRenderer( window1, -1 , SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

  // Set background
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255 );
  SDL_RenderClear( renderer );
  SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

  // Set circle's position
  int x = 100; int y = 100;
  int radius = 40;

  // Loop to hold the window in screen
  bool running = true;
  while(running)  {

        SDL_Event event1;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event1) !=0){

              // CIRCLE FUNCTION ??????
              functionSDLcircle(x, y, radius);

              if(event1.type ==SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                    switch (event1.key.keysym.sym){
                    case SDLK_RETURN:
                       running = false;
                       break;
                       }
                 }
           }
     }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want higher-level functions like circles without grabbing a full game engine, I would recommend the excellent [SFML (Simple Fast Media Library)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nothing like that off-the-shelf in the SDL_Renderer system.

You'll have to roll your own using `SDL_RenderDrawLines()`/OpenGL or switch to something like [SDL2_gfx](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sdl2gfx/).

Comment: thanks genpfault. yes, i have sdl2. Can you guide me how is with the sdl2_gfx?